# XSD for element with required attribute and required subelement

Tags: xml, xsd

A customer requires (for no reason I can understand) that we send him XML files containing, in part:

```
<ANNEAL>
    <CHARACTERISTIC NAME="CHARGE">
        <VALUE>23</VALUE>
    </CHARACTERISTIC>
    <CHARACTERISTIC NAME="POSITION">
        <VALUE>3</VALUE>
    </CHARACTERISTIC>
    <CHARACTERISTIC NAME="REANNEAL_HOLD">
        <VALUE>N</VALUE>
    </CHARACTERISTIC>
    <CHARACTERISTIC NAME="FINAL_COLDSPOT">
        <VALUE></VALUE>
    </CHARACTERISTIC>
    <CHARACTERISTIC NAME="FINAL_HOTSPOT">
        <VALUE/>
    </CHARACTERISTIC>
</ANNEAL>
```

I am trying to create an XSD type named CharacteristicType that will require the following:

1. The name of the element will be `CHARACTERISTIC`
2. The element will have no value
3. The element will have exactly one attribute named `NAME` of type string
4. The element will have one subelement named `VALUE` of type string
5. The `VALUE` subelement may or may not have a value.

I haven't yet created a type definition that Visual Studio likes.  Here's my latest attempt:

```
  <xs:complexType name="DateCharacteristicType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="cname">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="VALUE"/>
          </xs:sequence>
            <!--<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="CHARACTERISTIC"/>
            </xs:restriction>-->
          <xs:attribute type="NonEmptyString" name="NAME"/>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I'm sure I'll have to use a one-element enumeration to restrict the name of the outer element to `CHARACTERISTIC`.  Or will I?  Come to think of it, that would have to apply to the value of the element, not the name of it.  I think I'm going to have to compromise on requirement 1, and have to name every element `CHARACTERISTIC` myself.

Answer (score 1):

That's terrible XML design, but anyway...

- Required element: Use `minOccurs="1"` (or omit as default).
- Required attribute:  Use `use="required"`.

### XSD

Here's an XSD for it as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="ANNEAL">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CHARACTERISTIC" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="VALUE" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="NAME" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yeah, my reaction to that design was to ask my boss if the company would pay to fly me the customer's site and slap some idiot upside the head.  Unfortunately, he said no.